# Initializing complex number array in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, complex-numbers

I need to create an array that consists of complex numbers. I used the following code to initialize it.

```
std::complex<double> Uf[2]={(1, 2),(3, 4)};
```

I am expecting Uf[0] to be `1 + 2*i` and `Uf[1]` to be `3+ 4*i` but when I debug the program, I found out that imaginary values are shown as real and surprisingly imaginary value is zero for both numbers (i.e. `Uf[0]` is real: `2.0000..` imag: `0.0000`.... and `Uf[1]` is real: `4.0000`.. imag: `0.0000`.. . Can somebody explain me how to sort this out?

Thanks

Comment: I am not 100% sure but I think `std::vector` would be a better choice in this case!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's because you're using the *comma operator*, so the complex values will be initialized with `2` and `4` respectively. Replace the parentheses with curly-braces instead:

```
std::complex<double> Uf[2]={{1, 2},{3, 4}};
```

---

If the above doesn't work, your compiler is not C++11 compatible, and you have to explicitly create the array complex members:

```
std::complex<double> Uf[2]={std::complex<double>(1, 2),std::complex<double>(3, 4)};
```

Comment: No. It's not working for me. I get the following compiler error. error C2552: 'Uf' : non-aggregates cannot be initialized with initializer list
1>          'std::complex<double>' : Types with a base are not aggregate

Answer (score 3):

You are initializing the array wrong. Try this:

```
std::complex<double> Uf[2]={{1, 2},{3, 4}};
```